# ionic 2 couchdb pouchdb : how to get data which is not synced yet

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

i have a feeling that issue i am having facing is some stupid simple basic thing but i m still not able to figure it out.

I have having couchdb server which have thousands of documents. which are categories as type:topics and type:quiz.  basically topic documents contains list of quiz documents ids  and the type quiz documents contain the question and answer

Sample : topic document

```
{
   "_id": "topic-57913023930b4",
   "_rev": "1-1b8968c43bacffa849fab9bc62fbe910",
   "name": "Programming Languages",
   "type": "topic",
   "pid": "topic-57913023930b4",
   "totalQuiz": 19,
   "quiz": [
       {
           "id": "quiz-5790b7035f496"
       },
       {
           "id": "quiz-5790b7fbacc8e"
       },
       {
           "id": "quiz-5790b3291766d"
       },
       {
           "id": "quiz-5790afc077f64"
       }

   ]
}
```

sample: quiz document

```
{
   "_id": "quiz-5790a476e184c",
   "_rev": "1-48acc3b900b6010cf3d527fcf26f8e0c",
   "question": "this is a question",
   "correctanswer": 0,
   "answers": [
       "option 1",
       "option 2",
       "option 3",
       "option 4"
   ]  
}
```

Now to sync the server database to the local database .if i sync whole database then my local database like this :

```
this.db = new PouchDB('mydb');   
 this.remote ='http://IP_ADDRESS:5984/mydb';
 let options = {
      live: true,
      retry: true,
      continuous: true      
    };
 this.db.sync(this.remote, options);
```

then my local database will get huge in just few minutes because my server contains thousands of documents. i wish to avoid that and download documents only on demand. i am not sure how to do that

if i use some basic filter  to pull only the documents that are of type : topics at the start like this :

```
this.db = new PouchDB('mydb');   
 this.remote ='http://IP_ADDRESS:5984/mydb';
    let options = {
      live: true,
      retry: true,
      continuous: true,
      filter:  function (doc) {
                return doc.type === 'topic';
              }
    };
    this.db.sync(this.remote, options);
```

if i do above then only topics documents get pulled but i dont have access to the quiz documents at all. perhaps i need to disable syncing and figure out a way to download data only on demand. not sure how to do that though :(

But anyway even i let the whole database gets synced automatically in the constructor. still it takes along time to replicate the database to the local database .

lets say in the home page of the app i want to display a topic 'Programming Languages' from the document id : "_id": "topic-57913023930b4" . for that i made this code

```
ionViewLoaded(){     
     this.DataService.getDocument('topic-57913023930b4').then((result) => {
        this.data = result;
       }); 
}
```

and in my service i have this code:

```
getDocument(id) {      
          return new Promise(resolve => {         
            this.db.get(id).then((result) =>{                    
              this.data=result;          
              resolve(this.data);                 
            }).catch((error) => {   
              console.log(error);   
            });       
          });
    }
```

But when the app starts it hasnt pulled all those thousand documents yet so my local database dont have document with id 'topic-57913023930b4' . it might take several minutes to get that document if i rely on the constructor's data sync code.

so i need a way to pull this data from the couchdb server at this very moment. but i m not sure how to do that. although i know can use HTTP request but it wont get synced with the pouchdb local database.

Please guide me in the right direction. i have been trying to make this working since yesterday but not able to figure this out.

---

As Alexis Côté advised :

Though i may have to sync the local database to the server database still i been working on the idea that you suggested :
i.e. if the local storage dont have the data yet i will do a http request to the document directly and get the data. and then store that data in the pouchdb.

```
fetchDoc(id){
    return new Promise(resolve => {     
        this.db.get(id).then((result) =>{                    
            this.data=result;          
            resolve(this.data);               
        }).catch((error) => {   
            console.log('data is not in the PouchDB yet. so calling HTTP REQUEST');             
            this.data=this.httpRequest(id);
            console.log(this.data);             
            resolve(this.data); 

        }); 

}

httpRequest(id){
    let url='http://ip_address:5984/mydb/"+id;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('fetchin url :'+url);
        this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
                resolve(this.data);
            });
    });
}
```

This give me data immediately. 
But after getting this data if i try to store this data in the pouchdb then i get this error " missing _ID " 
when i print the data which is returned from the httRequest function is gives me this wierd object

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array[0]}
```

now i m struggling with this ZoneAwarePromise :( and how to get the data stored in the pouchdb correctly.

i will have to sync this file back to couchdb as this file will also have user comments.

Comment: You rely on the local database for "offline" capabilities?

Comment: Yes .if the user is in offline mode then data should be fetched from pouchdb

Comment: Will the documents "pulled" synced back to the remoteDB? If no, you could make a "request" fonction. This function would fetch the documents from the localDB if they're present. If not, the function would fetch from the remoteDB and add the documents to the localDB. This would be like a "cache".

Comment: Thanks for the response. please read the edited version of the question. i am trying to work on way you suggested

Comment: Question. Why don't you stay with PouchDB for your requests?

Comment: that's what i want to do but how?  couchDb sync is happening slowly. and i want to display the data as soon as the user launch the app. even if i try to replicate single document  with let options = {
   live: true,
   retry: true,
   doc_ids: ['topicName']
  };  
  this.db.replicate.from(this.remote, options)     even then its taking log time to pull the data.  all the example i have been finding on internet is about syncing all the documents from couchdb but unable to figure out how to pull one document instantly on demand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118238/discussion-between-sourabh-swarnkar-and-alexis-cote).